# Adding two integer variables and displaying output C

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior, format-specifiers

I am trying to create a simple program in C, that adds two numeric variables.
I have tried to validate the inputs, however now the program does not display an answer, simply `0.000000000`

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int input, temp, status, numberOne, numberTwo, ans;

int main(void){

first();
second();
add();
}


int first(void){
    printf("Please enter your number: ");
    status = scanf("%d", &input);
    while(status!=1){
        while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        printf("Invalid input... please enter a number: ");
        status = scanf("%d", &input);

    }
    numberOne = input;
}

int second(void){
    printf("Please enter your second number: ");
    status = scanf("%d", &input);
    while(status!=1){
        while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        printf("Invalid input... please enter a number: ");
        status = scanf("%d", &input);
        }
    numberTwo = input;
}

int add(void){
    ans=numberOne+numberTwo;
    printf("The answer is %f", ans);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result should be having a `%d` format specifier instead of `%f`

```
printf("The answer is %d", ans);
```

Note:- The `%d` format specifier is for integers and `%f` is generally used used for float.

In your case you are getting the two input integers using the below code:

```
status = scanf("%d", &input);
```

So the `%d` here sigifies that the two numbers are integers. Now adding them will give the result as an integer. Hence you should use the %d only to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

As per chapter 7.21.6.1, `C11` standard, paragraph 9

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

In your code, `ans` is of type `int`. You've to use `%d` format specifier, not `%f`.

```
 printf("The answer is %f", ans);
```

should be

```
 printf("The answer is %d", ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 printf("The answer is %f", ans);
```

should be

```
 printf("The answer is %d", ans);
```

`%d` is the right format specifier to print the integer, using wrong format specifier leads to undefined behvaior that is what you are seeing